# Problem with with respective operations in c#

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, data-structures, numbers

I have problem with solution in this example Say Me Please Operations(codeKata):

You have a string with N numbers, every 2 numbers after an operation(?) return next number in this string.
Write a function who return new string with respective operations :

1)addition,

2)subtraction,

3)multiplication,

4)division.

```
example: for string stringNumbers = "9 4 5 20 25"

 your function must return:

"subtraction, multiplication, addition"
```

because,

- 9 - 4 = 5 - substraction,
- 4 * 5 = 20 - multiplication,
- 5 + 20 = 25 - addition,

  **My Code:**

  ```
  int x = 0,add = 0, multi = 0, sub = 0, divi = 0, z = 0;
  var v = stringNumbers.Split(' ').ToArray();
  string s = "";
  if (v.Length >= 3)
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
          for (int j = i + 1; j < v.Length; j++)
              for (int k = j + 1; k < v.Length; k++)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(k);
                  x = int.Parse(v[i]);
                  z = int.Parse(v[j]);
                  add = x + z;
                  multi = x * z;
                  sub = x - z;
                  divi = x / z;

                  if (add == int.Parse(v[k]))
                  {
                      s += "addition, ";
                  }
                  else if (sub == int.Parse(v[k]))
                  {
                      s += "subtraction, ";
                  }
                  else if (multi == int.Parse(v[k]))
                  {
                      s += "multiplication, ";
                  }
                  else if (divi == int.Parse(v[k]))
                  {
                      if (int.Parse(v[i]) != 0)

                          s += "division, ";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      break;
                  }
              }
  }
  else
      return "";
  s = s.Remove(s.Length - 2, 2);
  return s;
  ```

I passed sample test, but no this one.I dont know where is issue.

[image: What is wrong ?]

Thanks for help! 
This is my third post sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: I will try repair this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is a lot simpler and will accomplish the same without the layers of loops you are using:

```
public static string ProcessOperations(string numbers)
{
    string[] numberArray;
    string returnValue = string.Empty;

    numberArray = numbers.Split(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.Length - 2; i++)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(numberArray[i], out int a) &&
            int.TryParse(numberArray[i + 1], out int b) &&
            int.TryParse(numberArray[i + 2], out int c))
        {
            if (a + b == c)
                returnValue += "addition, ";
            else if (a - b == c)
                returnValue += "subtraction, ";
            else if (a * b == c)
                returnValue += "multiplication, ";
            else if (a / b == c)
                returnValue += "division, ";
        }
    }

    returnValue = returnValue.TrimEnd(new[] { ',', ' ' });

    return returnValue;
}
```

Testing with the only value you supplied:

```
?ProcessOperations("9 4 5 20 25");
subtraction, multiplication, addition
```

This uses a single loop that operates up until the end position - 2.  It then parses the items at position `i`, `i + 1`, and `i + 2` (into `a`, `b`, and `c`).  Following that, it checks which arithmatic operation is used to calculate `c` from `a` and `b`.

There's a `TrimEnd` just before the return to remove any spurious commas and spaces.

Notes: There's no error checking is no arithmatic operation will give the result.  The division is integer division so will not work with floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `v.length` is `5`.

You want to execute the following loops passes:

1. i=0, j=1, k=2
2. i=1, j=2, k=3
3. i=2, j=3, k=4

But that's not what you're doing. You have `j` and `k` change semi-independently of `i`.

1. i=0, j=1, k=2
2. i=0, j=1, k=3
3. i=0, j=1, k=4
4. i=0, j=2, k=3
5. i=0, j=2, k=4
6. i=0, j=3, k=4
7. i=1, j=2, k=3
8. i=1, j=2, k=4
9. i=1, j=3, k=4
10. i=2, j=3, k=4

To get the desired outcome, you should only have one loop. You can derive the other values from the loop variable.

You could derive `j` and `k` from `i` as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.Length - 2; ++i) {
   int j = i + 1;
   int k = i + 2;
   ...
}
```

Or you could could derive `i` and `j` from `k` as follows:

```
for (int k = 2; k < v.Length; ++k) {
   int i = k - 2;
   int j = k - 1;
   ...
}
```

Either way, the `if (v.Length >= 3)` check is useless. The `for` already performs an equivalent check. I also recommend parsing the elements of `v` once each (before the main loop) rather than parsing them repeatedly.